# "Packet for query is too large" error. Where to change max_allowed_packet variable?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, mysql-workbench, configuration-files

I am having a problem, I imported a spring boot project from git, the code is working perfectly fine in my teammates computers, but I get an error That I don't know how to solve, while running my java application I get this error :

```
Packet for query is too large (1072729 > 1048576). You can change this value on the server by setting the max_allowed_packet' variable.
```

I read some answers about the subject, What I understood is that I have to make a change in my.ini file and change this value :

```
max_allowed_packet=500M
```

But it seems like I am unable to find my file location, I am working with MySQLWorkebench and I dont know where to find this file to make my change or any change.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: On Windows? or a *NIX

Comment: @RiggsFolly On Windows

Comment: Did you install MySQL manually or did you install it through a package like XAMPP or WAMPServer

Comment: WAMPSERVER , That is what I used

Comment: Then its in `wamp\bin\mysql\mysqlx.y.z\my.ini`

Comment: or if 64bit WAMPServer then `wamp64\bin\mysql\mysqlx.y.z\my.ini`

Comment: Found it, Can you rewrite this as anwser so I can mark it as a correct one ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will find `my.ini` in either

#### 32bit WAMPServer

```
C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysqlx.y.z\my.ini
```

#### 64bit WAMPServer

```
C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysqlx.y.z\my.ini
```

where `mysqlx.y.z` is the version of MySQL that you have installed. Remember there may be more than one version installed so check with the wampmanager icon menu which one is currently active

In `my.ini` under the section `[wamp]` or `[wamp64]` you will see the parameter

```
max_allowed_packet = 1M
```

Change that to the value you believe is required.

> Remember to restart MySQL (using the wampmanager icon menus) after saving your change to `my.ini`